# Android: SwipeRefreshLayout containing Toolbar and RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, which contains a `Toolbar` and `RecyclerView`.
When I scroll the `RecyclerView`, the `Toolbar` is hidden. The problem is, that when refreshing the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, it shows the spinner but it is actually hidden by the `Toolbar`.

The way I have my XML is this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nearby_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <followtheheat.ui.views.FthTextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        xmlns:fth="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fth:font_family="osp_din"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Is there a way to do this in which the Toolbar isn't hidden when refreshing the RecyclerView, but it can still be hidden?
I did it following [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/) tutorial.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a RelativeLayout to align the SwipeRefreshLayout below the Toolbar. This way neither the toolbar nor refresh indicator won't be drawn on top of each other.

If you can't use a RelativeLayout, just define the Toolbar in xml before the SwipeRefreshLayout. This way the refresh indicator will be drawn on top of the Toolbar.

**Edit:**
If you want to use the second approach, on the showViews() method you should programmatically add a marginTop = ?attr/actionBarSize to the SwipeRefreshLayout, and remove it on hideView().